# gitlab-ci ssh connexion fail

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like run ssh connexion on my production server from gitlab-ci runner :

```
deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "====== Deploy to production server ======"
    - apk update && apk upgrade
    - apk add git openssh bash

    # Add target server`s secret key
    - mkdir ~/.ssh
    - echo $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
    - cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - echo "Test ssh connection"
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T "$TARGET_SERVER_USER@$TARGET_SERVER_HOST"

    # Delploy
    - echo "make deploy"
    - pm2 deploy ecosystem.config.js production
```

The ssh test failed with this error :

```
$ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T "$TARGET_SERVER_USER@$TARGET_SERVER_HOST"
Warning: Permanently added 'xxxxxxx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

My all variable is add on secret variable on gitlab project

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: Try running ssh with `-vvv` to get lots of debug information. Can you connect when you run the code locally?

Comment: I am having similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57290734/gitlab-ssh-host-key-verification-failed-inside-gitlab-ci