# SSH Host Key Verification Failed inside GitLab CI

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

**Local Setup**

I created a public and private SSH key via the `ssh-keygen` command.

I decided to setup the private key locally first, before setting it up on my repo's gitlab CI.

I setup the public key on the server (in this case, another gitlab repo, but this may change in the future and shouldn't affect the question).

I successfully communicated with the server locally via the following command  (in this case I am using SSH via `git`, but this again may change in the future):

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:...../......git
```

**GitLab CI Setup**

I then decided to setup the private key and communication on gitlab CI.

Inside my repo, I navigated to Settings `->` Continuous Integration `->` Variables, and added the following environment variables:

- `SSH_DEPLOY_PRIVATE_KEY` - I used to same private key that I used locally
- `SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS`

  - I took the `gitlab.com` known host from my local computer's `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file
  - `gitlab.com,35.231.145.151 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBFSMqzJeV9rUzU4kWitGjeR4PWSa29SPqJ1fVkhtj3Hw9xjLVXVYrU9QlYWrOLXBpQ6KWjbjTDTdDkoohFzgbEY=`

I then setup the SSH inside `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
script:
  - apt-get install openssh-client -y
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - echo "$SSH_DEPLOY_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
  - mkdir -p /.ssh && touch /.ssh/known_hosts
  - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" >> /.ssh/known_hosts
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

This seemed to work fine and I got the following message: `Identity added: (stdin) (runner@....)`

I then added the same `git clone` command to communicate with the server, and it failed with the following error:

```
Cloning into '......'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Testing locally still works. I used the same commands above to setup the SSH locally (except I used `pacman -S openssh` to install instead).

How do I fix this?

**Edit**

I'm aware that I can execute `ssh-keyscan` directly in the GitLab CI and this should in theory solve the problem, but from what I know, this is susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks. I'm trying to find a more secure solution.

**Edit 2**

After running `ssh-keyscan` directly in the GitLab CI, I get the same error message.

Verbose output is the same:

```
$ GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone git@gitlab.com:..../.....git deployed
Cloning into 'deployed'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**Edit 3**

Seems to be connected to the internet. Plus `apt-get install` wouldn't work otherwise.

[image]

**Edit 4**

I don't understand why this is such a difficult task. I followed [this article](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/README.html) and am doing everything correctly. There seems to be plenty of other similar questions, which also do not have any answers. Is this just an issue with GitLab CI that we have no control over?

I'm also now thinking that it has something to do with the fact that the SSH server is another GitLab repo. Maybe GitLab CI blocks SSH connections within the same network. Not sure why but it's a possibility. Also don't know how you'd connect without SSH.

**Edit 5**

The verbose output clearly was not working using `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`, so I tried an ssh connection without git:

```
ssh -vvvv git@gitlab.com
```

Log output:

```
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u5, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [35.231.145.151] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "gitlab.com" from file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup umac-64-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: setup umac-64-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA f1:d0:fb:46:73:7a:70:92:5a:ab:5d:ef:43:e2:1c:35
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "gitlab.com" from file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "35.231.145.151" from file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Host key verification failed.
```

The second-last line indicates that it's trying to communicate with the terminal using the `/dev/tty` file. Of course, this script is running in a non-interactive manor so it fails. Shouldn't it be using my key instead of requesting a passphrase from the terminal?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may need to try setting the mode to 644 rather than 700. 644 is what is suggested in the [Verifying the SSH host keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#verifying-the-ssh-host-keys) documentation, and is also what SSH uses for this file by default. Some parts of SSH are very particular about this - I'm not sure if known_hosts is particular.

The docs also mention you should set the value of `SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS` variable to the *entire* output of `ssh-keyscan` since there are multiple keys.

EDIT:

The following `.gitlab-ci.yml` worked for me on GitLab.com. Note the use of `~/.ssh/` rather than `/.ssh/`.

```
image: ubuntu:latest

test_job:
  script:
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install openssh-client git-core -y
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - echo "$SSH_DEPLOY_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh && touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - git clone git@gitlab.com:gitlab-org/gitlab-ce.git
```

Comment: I tried putting the entire output of `ssh-keyscan` into `SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS`, but this didn't work so I instead put the contents of the local `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. I'll try changing to `644`

Comment: Nope that didn't fix it. P.S your link is broken.

Comment: I fixed the link.

Comment: I updated my answer with a working `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

Comment: That's it! It's working! Such a simple fix to add `~`. I can't believe it!

Comment: Whoo! Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 6):

A server can have multiple signatures in case of load balanced server. Ideal way is to change

```sh
- echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" >> /.ssh/known_hosts
```

to

```sh
- ssh-keyscan www.gitlab.com >> /.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I should have mentioned that I knew about this already, but this is susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks, right? Is there another solution? It doesn't really matter for my project but I'm trying to figure out a secure solution. I will actually test that though to make sure that the known hosts is the issue.

Comment: Btw I realised a mistake because of copy paste it should `echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`, I assume `~` works in this

Comment: Also I would suggest to use the verbose mode as shown in https://askubuntu.com/a/620985

Comment: Can you add curl ipinfo.io and make sure the net is working inside the container

Comment: I just realized you also said to include the `~` home symbol, so now two people solved my problem. Adding the home symbol at the time didn't fix it because I was in the middle of trying out other things to fix it :facepalm:

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using the same private key. Both for security reasons and because it might cause other problems. Also, make sure the `authorized_keys` file contains the public key on the server you want to access, otherwise the whole thing can't work.
I'm assuming you've followed a guide along the lines of [this one](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/README.html)?

Hope this does something.

Comment: "I wouldn't recommend using the same private key?" You mean the same one locally as on gitlab CI? If so, I'm not using that one locally, I was just testing it locally to figure out if the problem is in the keys or if the problem is on the gitlab CI.

Comment: Yep I followed that guide. I'm not in control of the server - the server is another gitlab repo (I setup public key using their user interface). However, testing it locally worked, so, from what I know, this can't be the issue.

Comment: Yeah, that's the one I meant. Sorry, just a misunderstanding on my part :D
Sorry, I'm a bit out of ideas right now. Good luck, if I have any ideas I'll be back.